# Alamofire parse response incorrectly

Tags: json, swift, api, rest, alamofire

Trying out the request on Postman, the "data" of the response is an empty dictionary.

[image: postman response]

However, when I try that in swift using Alamofire, "data" gets misinterpreted as an empty array. What could I be doing wrong?
[image: alamofire response]

Raw response using `debugPrint(response)` prints the following:

```
[Response]:
    [Status Code]: 200
    [Headers]:
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"
        Cache-Control: no-cache, private
        Content-Encoding: br
        Content-Length: 71
        Content-Type: application/json
        Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2023 16:32:18 GMT
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.24
        x-ratelimit-limit: 60
        x-ratelimit-remaining: 59
    [Body]:
        {"status":false,"message":"Kullan\u0131c\u0131 bilgileri hatal\u0131.","data":[]}
```

Tried changing the encoding and headers of the request, none was helpful.

Comment: I'd recommend ditching Alamofire in favor of `URLSession` and `Codable`.

Comment: And please post text as actual text, not as pictures.

Comment: "from: ..." shows it's an array, and that seems to be the raw JSON you receive...

Comment: Could you print `String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8)`? That should be the raw JSON you get, and it seems to me it's a array they, not a dictionary.

Comment: @Larme, it is an array. ```Optional("{\"status\":false,\"message\":\"Kullan\\u0131c\\u0131 bilgileri hatal\\u0131.\",\"data\":[]}")```. What I don't understand is that, why is it a dictionary on Postman? Also our Android team don't have a problem either.

Comment: Could you ask Alamofire to produce a cURL equivalent of your request, and same with POSTMAN. Check the result JSON, and maybe compare the two requests to find difference that could explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this odd way of representing `null` from a server (openweathermap), where instead of `null`, it uses `{}`.
To work with this, I used a custom decoder, something like:

```
// for the case where we have:  "data": { } instead of, "data": null

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let theData = try? values.decode([String].self, forKey: .data) {
        self.data = theData
    } else {
        self.data = nil
    }
    // ....other keys
}
```

with declaration, `let data: [String]?` or whatever the array holds.

Note this is a `JSONDecoder` behaviour, not Alamofire, I was using `URLSession.shared...` with this. When the `JSONDecoder` tries to decode this `{}`, it crashes, because it is not an a `null` and it not an array either. Postman is probably more forgiving than Swift `JSONDecoder`. Alamofire tries to decode `data` as an array, because you probably declared it as an array in your struct/class to decode.

EDIT-1:

here is the SwiftUI code I used to test my answer (same approach for UIKit and Alamofire):

```
struct RequestResponse: Decodable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String?
    var data: [String]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status, message, data
    }
    
    // for the case where we have: "data": { } instead of, "data": null
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.status = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        self.message = try values.decode(String?.self, forKey: .message)
        if let theData = try? values.decode([String].self, forKey: .data) {
            self.data = theData
        } else {
            self.data = nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var response: RequestResponse?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let results = response {
                Text(results.status ? "true" : "false")
                Text(results.message ?? "no message")
                ForEach(results.data ?? [], id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("\(item)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let json = """
{
   "status": false,
   "message": "some message here",
   "data": {}
}
"""
            // simulated API data from the server
            let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(RequestResponse.self, from: data)
                print("\n---> decoded: \(decoded) \n")
                response = decoded
            } catch {
                print("\n---> error: \n \(error)\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. However, can you elaborate more on how this is a `JSONDecoder` and not something related to Alamofire. I'm printing the response before reaching to the decoding line, and it shows `data` there as an array too.

Comment: I'm no expert in Alamofire, and without the code you use it is difficult to say what is going on.

Comment: Alamofire shouldn't touch the received data. It might send parameter that asks explicitly for `[]` instead of `{}`, but then it's up t the request you make. I ask for the cURL to compare, but you didn't provided them. And you can also do the cURL in the Terminal and see how is the response.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Alamofire issue, it's an error from `JSONDecoder`. You can check your actual response by printing the raw response in Alamofire (which you don't post any code for).

```swift
.response<...> { response in 
  debugPrint(response)
}
```

That will print a `String` version of the response body (unless it's very large) which you can use to see what you're actually receiving.

You can also check your actual response using a proxy like Proxyman or a traffic inspector like Wireshark and see what you're actually getting. It seems likely you're actually receiving an array.

Comment: This seems to be missing the issue. The OP shows in one context that the `data` field is a dictionary but the JSON being received via Alamofire in the running app has the `data` field as an array. The question is about that unexpected difference.

Comment: @HangarRash Initially the question was about why it was saying there was an array when a dictionary was expected. Turns out it's actually an array. Now it's a question of why it's an array. Which is a new question for the backend.